# How to import data from a hbase table to hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I've created a Hbase table like this,

```
create 'student','personal'
```

and I've put some data into it like this.

```
    ROW                         COLUMN+CELL
 1 column=personal:age, timestamp=1456224023454, value=20

 1 column=personal:name, timestamp=1456224008188, value=pesronA

 2                          column=personal:age, timestamp=1456224891317, value=13

 2                          column=personal:name, timestamp=1456224868967, value=pesronB

 3                          column=personal:age, timestamp=1456224935178, value=21

 3                          column=personal:name, timestamp=1456224921246, value=personC

 4                          column=personal:age, timestamp=1456224951789, value=20

 4                          column=personal:name, timestamp=1456224961845, value=personD


 5                          column=personal:age, timestamp=1456224983240, value=20

 5                          column=personal:name, timestamp=1456224972816, value=personE


-
```

I want to import this data to a hive table. I wrote a hive query for that like this

```
CREATE TABLE hbaseStudent(key INT,name STRING,age INT) STORED BY'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,personal:age,personal:name") TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "student")
```

But when I execute the query error comes out like this.

> Driver returned: 1.  Errors: OK
>   FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration

what should i do?

Comment: You are just creating a way to query hbase data through hive interface, you are not importing data from hbase -> hive (hdfs).

Answer (score 1):

I tried this thing and it worked try replacing all the double quotes (`"`) with single quotes (`'`). It will work & also try to add terminator `;` in last line.